# System.AccessViolationException with Sqlite.Connection.LoadExtension()

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

I have an old 2005 VB.NET application that requires a Sqlite update for JSON functions.

I have downloaded and installed "sqlite-netFx20-setup-bundle-x86-2005-1.0.109.0.exe". I removed the Reference to the older version, and re-referenced to this new version. I compiled a run the program - all seemed to be okay.

Using an online example for JSON, put the following code behind a TestButton:-

```
jsondb.SQL = "CREATE TABLE user (name, phone)"
ExecuteSQLiteCommand(jsondb)
jsondb.SQL = "INSERT INTO user (name, phone) values('oz',  json('{""""cell"""":""""+491765"""", """"home"""":""""+498973""""}'))"
ExecuteSQLiteCommand(jsondb)
```

When the "INSERT" is executed, I get "json function not found".

After more research, I found that I had to enable the json extensions with:-

```
mySQLdb.Connection.Open()
mySQLdb.Connection.EnableExtensions(True)
mySQLdb.Connection.LoadExtension("SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
```

Initially, the .LoadExtension failed because the "SQLite.Interop.dll" module was not found.

I found a copy of this module in "sqlite-netFx20-binary-Win32-2005-1.0.109.0.zip" and copied it into the Sqlite install directory, and changed the .LoadExension method to:-

```
mySQLdb.Connection.LoadExtension("C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\2005\bin\SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
```

Now the .LoadExension method raises an exception "System.AccessViolationException".

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that because I have the Sqlite Reference attribute CopyLocal=true, then the folder location for System.Data.SQLite.dll and SQLite.Interop.dll need to be the same.

Changing the .LoadExtension to:-

```
mySQLdb.Connection.LoadExtension(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
```

Fixed this.